# How to run powershell commands from command line to use current directory as a param?

Tags: powershell

In powershell (running from windows command line), If I do

`Get-Location`, it shows me the current working directory. And if I have this command

`dir -Path "C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\project\src" -Filter bot.ts`

it does the search. But how do I replace `path` with `Get-Location`? It doesn't work when I try it, it seems to try to find a program called Get-Location?

Comment: there is an automatic $Var named `$PSScriptRoot` that will contain the dir that a script was loaded from ... and that will let you call things in that dir. if you need the "current working dir", then just use `-Path (Get-Location)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subexpression `$()`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $(Get-Location).Path -Filter bot.ts
```

Or use the automatic variable `$PWD`

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $PWD

Path
----
C:\Users\Neko

PS C:\Users\Neko> $PWD.Path
C:\Users\Neko
```

So

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD.Path -Filter bot.ts
```

By default `Get-ChildItem` (same as `dir` and `ls`) will work in the current directory so the `Path` switch is unneccesary.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter bot.ts
```